# Reshape data with separator using reshape2

Tags: r, reshape2

Im trying to use the reshape2 package to reshape my data but I'm getting an error. My data is as below:

```
mydata<-read.csv("Data.csv")
head(mydata)    
      Date  A.Price B.Price C.Price A.Rating B.Rating C.Rating
31/01/2012    1.273    3.11   1.215        5        4        3  
29/02/2012    1.393    3.19   1.205       10        8        7  
30/03/2012    1.367    3.15   1.076     10.5      9.5      7.5
```

My goal is to get it reshaped to this:

```
Date       ID  Price  Rating  
31/01/2012  A  1.273  5  
31/01/2012  B  3.11  4  
31/01/2012  C  1.215  3  
29/02/2012  A  1.393  10  
29/02/2012  B  3.19  8  
....
```

So far my code is:

```
mydata$ID <- sequence(nrow(mydata))  
out<-melt(reshape(mydata, direction = "long", 
  timevar = "Group", varying = names(mydata), sep = "."), 
       id.vars = c("ID", "Price","Rating"))
```

but im getting the error:

> Error in reshapeLong(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar, varying =
>   varying,  :    'varying' arguments must be the same length

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `melt` from `data.table` which can take multiple `measure` columns

```
library(data.table)
dM <- melt(setDT(mydata), measure=patterns('Price', 'Rating'), 
    variable.name='ID', value.name=c('Price', 'Rating'))
```

By default, the 'variable'(i.e. 'ID') column output as numeric index.  We can use `sub` to get the prefix from the column names and update the 'ID' column.

```
dM[, ID:= sub('\\..*', '', names(mydata)[-1])[ID]]
dM
#         Date ID Price Rating
#1: 31/01/2012  A 1.273    5.0
#2: 29/02/2012  A 1.393   10.0
#3: 30/03/2012  A 1.367   10.5
#4: 31/01/2012  B 3.110    4.0
#5: 29/02/2012  B 3.190    8.0
#6: 30/03/2012  B 3.150    9.5
#7: 31/01/2012  C 1.215    3.0
#8: 29/02/2012  C 1.205    7.0
#9: 30/03/2012  C 1.076    7.5
```

---

Or using `reshape` from `base R` and specify the `varying` as a list of column index.  We can get the index with `grep`

```
nm1 <- unique(sub('.*\\.', '', names(mydata)[-1])) 
res <- reshape(mydata, direction='long', varying= lapply(nm1, 
           grep, names(mydata)))
row.names(res) <- NULL
head(res)
#        Date time A.Price A.Rating id
#1 31/01/2012    1   1.273      5.0  1
#2 29/02/2012    1   1.393     10.0  2
#3 30/03/2012    1   1.367     10.5  3
#4 31/01/2012    2   3.110      4.0  1
#5 29/02/2012    2   3.190      8.0  2
#6 30/03/2012    2   3.150      9.5  3
```

---

Or another option would be `merged.stack` from `library(splitstackshape)`.  If we need to convert to 'long' format based on the suffix part in the column names, get the suffix of column names with `sub`, and use the `unique` elements in `var.stubs` along with specifying the `sep` as 'var.stubs`in`merged.stack`.

```
library(splitstackshape)
nm1 <- unique(sub('.*\\.', '', names(mydata)[-1]))#from above
merged.stack(mydata, var.stubs =nm1, atStart=FALSE, 
    sep='var.stubs')[, .time_1:= sub('[.]+', '', .time_1)][]
#         Date .time_1 Price Rating
#1: 29/02/2012       A 1.393   10.0
#2: 29/02/2012       B 3.190    8.0
#3: 29/02/2012       C 1.205    7.0
#4: 30/03/2012       A 1.367   10.5
#5: 30/03/2012       B 3.150    9.5
#6: 30/03/2012       C 1.076    7.5
#7: 31/01/2012       A 1.273    5.0
#8: 31/01/2012       B 3.110    4.0
#9: 31/01/2012       C 1.215    3.0
```

Comment: Thanks so much akrun! but is there a way to do it so that i can use the "." as a separator instead of typing out the names of the columns?

Comment: @richard_jokes  As both the prefix and suffix are varying across, one way would be to specify the columns in `varying` as a `list` in your reshape. i.e. `reshape(mydata, direction='long', varying=list(2:4, 5:7))`

Comment: @richard_jokes  I added some more options.  Hope it helps.

Comment: I see i see. Just to confirm, the reshape option requires me to specify the number of columns with the varying "variable" (eg price/rating sorry dont know what the proper term is..) but the other options do it automatically right?

Comment: sorry bout that..a newbie here haha. thank you so much akrun :)